# Como mudar hora, ler e fazer gráfico no MATLAB?

Tags: script, matlab, análise-de-dados

Sou estudante de meteorologia e analiso dados de torres micrometeorológicas. Em cada linha do meu arquivo, **.csv** possui código da torre, ano, dia juliano e hora minuto.
110,2015,005,2359

1º Gostaria de saber como faço para arrumar meu horário de 2359 para 23:59.
2º Plotar um gráfico e no meu Xlabel possuir o horário e que este horário no eixo x seja dinâmico ao meu zoom(se necessário).

Comment: Ficou meio confuso sobre o plot, plotar o que quais dados ?

Comment: Plotar dados de alta frequência.

Comment: OK você apresentou os dados, mas o seu plot tem que mostrar o que? eu digo quais valores? você disse que no eixo x vai ter os horários, mas quais valores vão estar relacionado a estes horários?

Comment: Dados de temperatura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom vamos lá, ter a hora em decimal pode ser algo interessante(inteligente), isso pode te ajudar na visualização dinâmica no eixo x durante o zoom:

Um exemplo:

```
max=33;
min=15;

t=(0:100:2359)

r1 = min + (max-min).*rand(length(t),1);

plot(t,r1)
```

Não estamos providos de todas as informações, então o código acima tenta simular os dados para demonstração, estou gerando randomicamente valores de temperatura entre `15` e `33` graus na variável `r1`, também não fazemos a mínima ideia de qual é a sua janela de amostragem, então mais uma vez só posso simular, a variável `t` gera linearmente a hora em modo decimal de `0` até `2359`, ou seja `24` horas espaçados de `1` em `1` horas (janela de amostragem), essa janela é de quanto em quanto tempo as medições são aferidas, este código retorna o seguinte plot:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com um zoom:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o eixo `X` vai dinamicamente mostrando os valores decimalmente.

OK você não quer que o valor da hora seja decimal, então você vai perder a dinâmica quando der zoom (óbvio o formato de hora é uma string e não número), pois bem veja como colocar a hora no formato convencional:

```
%em minutos
tempoamostragem=60;

max=33;
min=15;

dv = 0/24:(0.0666666666667*tempoamostragem)/96:23/24+4/96;
labelX=datestr(dv, 'HH:MM');
labelX=cellstr(labelX);

r1 = min + (max-min).*rand(length(labelX),1);
t=(1:1:length(labelX));

plot(t, r1);
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:length(labelX), 'XTickLabel', labelX);
```

Explicando alguns detalhes do código:

A variável `tempodeamostragem` já diz tudo é de quanto em quanto tempo a coleta foi efetuada, estou utilizando a função do matlab [datestr](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/datestr.html) para gerar um vetor de hora, a função utiliza como entrada outro vetor(`dv`) espaçado linearmente pelo tempo de amostragem por um 1 dia convertido em  quarto `24*4=96`, o valor `0.0666666666667` é equivalente a 1 minuto neste novo formato:

```
>> 24*60

ans =

        1440

>> 96/1440

ans =

    0.0667
```

Provando se é verdade mesmo:

```
>> 0.0666666666667*24*60

ans =

   96.0000
```

Perfeito, após todo esse malabarismo o matlab vai nos devolver um vetor com a hora no formato convencional e podemos utilizar esta variável dentro do `XTick`.

Plots:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com Zoom:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na realidade fica muito complicado tentar te ajudar sem ter os dados e uma explicação concisa do que você precisa, apenas falar `"preciso plotar"` não é suficiente para que possamos te ajudar com exatidão, em sua pergunta por exemplo, não sabemos de que maneira e de onde vem os dados da sua temperatura, o `CSV` demonstrado por você não apresenta valores de temperatura, não sabemos se suas amostras são fixas ou podem variar (a cada 5 minutos ou pode mudar para 10 minutos por exemplo), podemos te ajudar, mas precisamos que você descreva e apresente todas as informações disponíveis.

Comment: Muito obrigado.